# Typescript: pushing an object coverts number to string

Tags: typescript, string, numbers, push

I'm using Typescript (IONIC/Angular app) and I'm pushing an object with default values into an array, but the a variable of number type is getting converted into a string.

My type interfaces are

```
export interface HintsType {
    revealed?: boolean;
    type: 'string' | 'image';     
    value: any;                
    timeInterval?: number;    
}

export interface TestPieceInfo {
    seqNum: number;
    title: string;
    type: PieceTypes;
    answer: string;
    mainText: string;
    hints: HintsType[];
}

private piece: TestPieceInfo[]

code:

    addHint() {
    console.log('BEGIN addHint:);
    this.piece.hints.push({
      revealed: false,
      type: 'string',
      value: '',
      timeInterval: 5,
    });

    console.log('END of addHint: piece=', typeof this.piece.hints[0].timeInterval, this.piece.hints);
  }
```

When the code runs, my console.log shows that the correct information is being stored in the array, and that the typeof timeInterval is 'number,' but when it's displayed as part of the this.piece.hints array the timeInterval shows up as a string, in quotes, as "5".  Then, when this gets put into the database (Google Firestore) it is stored as a string instead of a number.

```
console.log output:
END of addHint: piece= **number ** [{…}]
0: 
revealed: false
timeInterval: "5"
type: "string"
value: ""

[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I've tried multiple things:

````
(1). .push({
      revealed: false,
      type: 'string',
      value: '',
      timeInterval: 5 as number
      })

(2). .push({
      revealed: false,
      type: 'string',
      value: '',
      timeInterval: 5 + 0
      })
```


(3). .push({ 
      revealed: false,
      type: 'string',
      value: '',
      timeInterval: null
      })
     this.piece.hints[this.piece.hints.length-1].timeInterval = 5
````

In every case the timeInterval property becomes a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  After much head-scratching and other investigation, I found the problem.

My data variable 'hints.timeInterval' was bound to an Angular form item with

```
[(ngModel)]="hints[i].timeInterval"
```

The html was using an ion-textarea tag, but with "type='number'".
I assumed that would force the form input to be a number, which it
does when you use ion-input but it's ignored when you use
ion-textarea.  So, the two-way binding between Angular and
Typescript was overriding the number as a string.  I changed
my html to use ion-input and it
works, so far.